# Born rule and angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables, born-rule

Physical interpretation of the wave function $\psi (x,t)$ is a probability amplitude for location $x$ and the Fourier transform of $\psi (x,t)$ can be interpreted as a probability amplitude for momentum $p$. Therefore $x$ and $p$ are conjugate variables and we can actually take the operator $\hat{p}=-i\hbar\nabla$ from the integral of the expectation value of momentum.

**My question is** that is there a similar calculation for angular momentum? The Born rule tells us that the operator is  $-i\hbar (x \times \nabla)$.

Comment: Erm... It's not the Born rule that tells us what is the operator, it's the definition basically of what is $L$. Could you elaborate on the $x$ and $p$ example so that it were more clear what do you ask

Comment: @OON I did some clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular momentum is conjugated to various angles in the spherical coordinates. Unlike usual coordinate $x$ those angles have limited range. So you may expect that just like in case of the Fourier transform on the limited range you will get not the integral but discrete series. However it doesn't have to look exactly like the usual Fourier series.

Indeed if we introduce the spherical coordinates,
\begin{equation}
x=r\cos\phi\sin\theta,\quad y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta,\quad z=r\cos\theta
\end{equation}
then any "good" wavefunction can be represented as a series,
\begin{equation}
\psi(r,\phi,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}\psi_{lm}(r)Y_{lm}(\phi,\theta)
\end{equation}
where $Y_{lm}$ are certain functions known as *spherical harmonics* that are orthonormal in the following sense,
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta \sin\theta\, Y_{l'm'}^\ast (\phi,\theta) Y_{lm}(\phi,\theta)=\delta_{ll'}\delta_{mm'}
\end{equation}
Because of that we find that,
\begin{equation}
\psi_{lm}(r)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta \sin\theta\,Y_{lm}^\ast(\phi,\theta) \psi(r,\phi,\theta)
\end{equation}

Now if we take $\hat{L}_z=xp_x-yp_y=-i\partial_\phi$ (I'll take $\hbar=1$) then you'll get that any term in the series is an *eigenfunction* of this operator,
\begin{equation}
\hat{L}_z\psi_{lm}(r)Y_{lm}=m\psi_{lm}(r)Y_{lm}
\end{equation}
If you try to do the same with $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$ this will not be the case. That's reflection of the fact that those operators *don't commute*. However if you take $\hat{L}^2=\hat{L}_x^2+\hat{L}_y^2+\hat{L}_z^2$ such operator *does commute* with $\hat{L}_z$ and,
\begin{equation}
\hat{L}^2\psi_{lm}(r)Y_{lm}=l\psi_{lm}(r)Y_{lm}
\end{equation}

Now you may consider $\psi_{lm}(r)$ as a new representation of the wavefunction. It's characterized by continuous parameter $r$ but also two integer parameter $l$ and $m$ with $l\geq 0,|m|\leq l$. Concerning those last two parameters the operators become simply matrices $A_{lm,l'm'}$ with $\hat{L}_z=m\delta_{mm'}$ and $\hat{L}^2=l\delta_{ll'}$. The expectation values can be written as,
\begin{equation}
\langle O\rangle = \int_{0}^{+\infty} r^2 dr\sum_{lm,l'm'} \psi_{lm}^\ast(r)\Big[\hat{O}_{lm,l'm'}\psi_{l'm'}\Big](r)
\end{equation}

Comment: @Hulkster well, you didn't clarified that exact point, what do you mean by "representing operator as expectation value". Do you mean representation like that? $K_p(x-y)=\int dp\, p e^{ip(x-y)}$ so that $\int dy K_p(x-y)\psi(y)=\hat{p}\psi(x)$?

Comment: @Hulkster Please also note that $\hat{x}\hat{p}$ is not Hermitian because $(\hat{x}\hat{p})^\dagger=\hat{p}\hat{x}\neq \hat{x}\hat{p}$ and therefore is not an observable

Comment: @Hulkster Ok, I'm simply asking you to write how exactly something similar to what you want works in case of $\langle p\rangle$ so we could pinpoint the analog in case of $L$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65594/discussion-between-oon-and-hulkster).